# Nginx subdomain returns 404

Tags: nginx

I have a domain and a subdomain, I have nuxtjs deployed on the main domain and it works fine. On the subdomain static files (images), and it does not work, constantly returns 404. I have already broken my head, tell me what could be the problem. Symlinks are created.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dev.venegrad.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.venegrad.com www.dev.venegrad.com;
    root /root/dev.venegrad.com;
    index index.html;
    autoindex on;

    location / {
  
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/venegrad.com

```
server {
    server_name venegrad.com www.venegrad.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/venegrad.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/venegrad.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.venegrad.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = venegrad.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name venegrad.com www.venegrad.com;
    #return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Does the directory `/root/dev.venegrad.com` exist? Does it have permissions set such that the www-data user can access it?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` blocks appear correctly. Check the error log. Use `curl` to confirm the response is coming from the subdomain using `http`. You only have an `http` service on the subdomain, so if the main domain uses HSTS headers that include subdomains, the browser will not be able to access the images.

Comment: www-data/, no there is /root/dev.venegrad.com/index.html

Comment: nginx -t is complete clear